# how to pass js variable to flask jinja function url_for

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

```
$("#getVerification").click(function () {
    var tmp=$("#cellphone").val();
    console.log(tmp);
    $.getJSON("{{ url_for('auth.sendsms', cellphone=tmp )}}",
        function(data){
    });
});
```

as the code above, I want to use the string variable `tmp` as a parameter in function `url_for`, but I can't figure out how,

Thanks A Lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass javascript variables to Jinja2 because of the way the template gets rendered.

Server side processing is done before client side.

Here is the order.

- Jinja2 processes the template into proper markup.
- The browser parses the markup into DOM and renders it.

> **The way this works only allows for passing Jinja2 variables to Javascript**.

You need to do without using `url_for` Jinja2 directive and build your URL client side.

```
var tmp=$("#cellphone").val();
    console.log(tmp);
    $.getJSON(["<url_path for auth.send_sms>", tmp].join("/"),
        function(data){
    });
```